# Getting current location from browser Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the current location using [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/y3h250ga/1/) it should log something in the console but doesn't, I also don't get my location from google's map's tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation

Here's the code from [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3h250ga/1/)

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    console.log(position.coords.latitude);
    console.log(position.coords.longitude); 
}
```

Update includes logging the result

Comment: You have two functions and never call either one.

Comment: You're getting it just fine. Just be sure to log it after you do, as @jaerk-kulikowski said

Comment: Make sure you are calling the `getLocation` function, otherwise your code seems to be working fine https://jsbin.com/kagiyim/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling it correctly, and if 
`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` returns valid result then it should print.  However, if there was an error then I suggest providing an option to catch an error as follows:

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
```

and define another function:

```
function showError( error ) {
    console.log( 'getCurrentPosition returned error', error);
}
```

For complete documentation please see [Geolocation.getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition)

Comment: @SamuelM. please check revised answer

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple, if someone is looking for only to see the location co-ordinates. Just use this on your browser console.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
    console.log(location.coords.latitude);
    console.log(location.coords.longitude);
});
```